# UIStatusBar color change to white when Splash screen showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, splash-screen

How to show Status Bar text color white when Splash screen is showing. I am using Default image for Splash screen for iPhone.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It has option to select light.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the above code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

//You can also use in View Controller.m file and add the following code

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Also if you don't want the status bar during app launch/Splash screen go to plist and set

Status bar is initially hidden=YES

It will hide the status bar during splash screen

Comment: I have already used this code but its make white status bar text  color when app launch. But I want when its showing default / slash screen

Answer (score 3):

Change *Status Bar Style* from *Default* to *Light*:

[image]

(click for bigger image)

Comment: There have no option for Light

Comment: Make sure that you select the app target in the sidebar. It won't work if you select the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the style of the status bar in Target. When you change it from here it will impact in your splash screen too.

[image: Select Target and change the style of status bar]
You can change your status bar color in app delegate class too 
Objective C Code:

```
// Change the status bar
UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
UIView *statusBar = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];

if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(254.0/255.0) green:(87.0/255.0) blue:(66.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];//set whatever color you like
}
```

Here is the swift code:

```
 //Status bar style and visibility
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    //Change status bar color
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    statusBar.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: CGFloat(254.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(87.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(66.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
```

Now, when you run your application you still see white background in splash screen just go to LaunchScreen storyboard and give the custom background color of the view  which you want to give and it works perfectly.